# netbeans - scp after build

Tags: netbeans, build, scp

I'd like to copy a file to a remote server with scp after building, using Netbeans.

What I do now manually is:

1. Clean and Build Main Project
2. scp dist/project.jar login@dest/...../......

Is there some way to automate this task? I tried looking at the build.xml file, but it really looks like something I don't want to mess with.

Thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 1):

I use [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/) to perform something similar to this. I monitor a local directory for file changes and it automatically transfers the changes files.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, see the scp task on ant's site: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html

An example from the site:

```
Copy a set of files to a directory
<scp todir="user:password@somehost:/home/chuck">
    <fileset dir="src_dir">
         <include name="**/*.java"/>
     </fileset>
</scp>

<scp todir="user:password@somehost:/home/chuck">
    <fileset dir="src_dir" excludes="**/*.java"/>
</scp>
```

You can hardcore the password inside the build task, but that's not a great idea. Better to use public keys.